# replace a string by another string custom pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a requirement to create custom pipe for replacing a string to another. If the string is 'true' then i have to display it as 'Yes'. If the string is 'false' then i have to display it as 'No'. I tried creating a custom pipe for it , but its not working.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'replaceText' })

export class ReplaceTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {       
        if (value) {
            console.log(value);
            if (value === "true") {
                value = value.replace("true", "Yes");               
            } else {
                value = value.replace("false", "No");                
            }          
            return value;
        }
    }
   
}
```

Can any one guide me please.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: The code seems ok (if you call it as | replaceText. Are you using it on async data? What exactly is not working? Do you get errors?

Comment: Could you please give further details about how did you use it in your component (html file or how did you call the transform method in the ts file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think the problem could be that you are passing boolean value as string.**

```html
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'replaceText'
})
export class ReplaceTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean): any {
    return value ? "Yes" : "No";
  }
}
```

```
Is work progressing: {{isRunning | replaceText }}
```

Comment: Glad I could help